# error Parse.json on windows OS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, windows, json

I have a problem with json on windows os with jquery :

I do that :

```
    $('person_select').selectChain({
            target: $('#closet_select'),
            url: function(value){
                return 'http://project.dev/person/' + value + '/closets.json';
            }
        });
```

the #person_select is a select field

In my controller, I do that :

```
format.json { render :json => @closets.map { |c| { :id  => c.id, :label => c.first_name} } }
```

and the values returned goes in the target (#closet_select).

This works really well when I am on mac but on windows OS it raise an error in the jQuery file :

```
data = window.JSON.parse( data );
```

If somebody know what is the problem I would be pleased to know it too ^^
Thanks

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As you use the JSON-property of the window-object, this not depends on jQuery or the OS, it depends on the browser-implementation of *window.JSON* . So which browser do you use, and if you use MSIE, do you use it in compatibility-mode or not?

Comment: It works on all the browsers (IE, firefox, safari, chrome) when I am on Mac but it never works when I'm on Windows and it is exactly the same version of the project on the both OS